# ERROR 1271 (HY000): Illegal mix of collations for operation '='

Tags: mysql, sql

При выполнении MySQL-запроса

```
SELECT * FROM Платежи WHERE id=1 AND По="(SELECT MAX(По) FROM Платежи WHERE id=1)";
```

Получаю ошибку

```
ERROR 1271 (HY000): Illegal mix of collations for operation '='
```

Comment: Название полей и таблиц на русском? 0_0 Дожили...
Вложенный запрос не надо обрамлять кавычками. Вы превратили его в строку.

Comment: ua6xh, спасибо :)

Comment: @ua6xh, подозреваю, что это просто как-то связано с 1с. Ну и в любимой моей Бухте тоже автоматически создаются поля "Ключ" и "Название".

Comment: @Fike, всё гораздо проще. Предполагалось, что менеджер будет добавлять новые значения в базу через Adminer, для него и сделал русские названия.

Answer (score 2):

Это делается немного по другому

```
SELECT * FROM Платежи WHERE id=1 ORDER BY По DESC LIMIT 1;
```